# Compare lines in text file to current time

Tags: php, file, time, compare

I'm trying to get some schedule times from a text file and display them. That part I did in the code below. But what I really need to do, rather than display all the times, is to compare the lines in the text file to the current time and only display the next scheduled time. I'm not quite sure how to do that part of it.

I figure I have to convert each line from string to time, then compare them to the current time, and display just the next one after the current time. I have no idea how to do that. Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php

$file_handle = fopen("schedule.txt", "rb");
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$currenttime = date('H:i:s');

while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('=', $line_of_text);

    print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";
}

fclose($file_handle);
?> 
<p>The current time is:</p>
<?php
print $currenttime;    
?>
```

Comment: You should post an example content of an input file

Comment: The text tile is simply this (but with line breaks):

10:00
14:00
16:00
20:00

Answer (score 0):

Since the text file is simply: 10:00 14:00 16:00 20:00
You should use ' ' (space) instead of '=' in the explore() function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file('schedule.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
//sort($lines);//sort $lines if not already sorted
date_default_timezone_set('America/Denver');
$currenttime = date('H:i:s');


$line = current($lines);
while($line !== false && $line < $currenttime) {
  $line = next($lines);
}

if($line > $currenttime) {
  echo $line;
} else {
  echo 'no next one found';
}
```